# Как вывести ссылку на изображение из БД в Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Здравствуйте. Пишу сайт на Django. Есть БД (sqlite) и там храниться ссылка на изображение такого вида `mainApp/img/logo.png`, само изображение находится в папке проекта.

В `html` пишу так:

```
{% for movie in object_list %}
       <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="card-movie">
           <a href="/movie/{{movie.id}}">
             <img src="{{movie.img}}">
             <p class="title-movie">{{movie.title}}</p>
           </a>
         </div>
       </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Но в итоге изображение не выводиться. Пробовал указывать абсолютный путь, типо: `C:\User\project\mainFolder\mainApp\static\mainApp\img\logo.png`, но это не помогло.

В `models.py` строку для записи ссылки указал как `img = models.CharField(max_length = 100)`

Вопрос:как сделать так чтобы изображение отобразилось? Подскажите пожалуйста, может я не так в принципе делают вывод и хранение изображений в БД?

Comment: Уверен на все 100 что решение корявое и в каких-то ситуациях сломается, но решил в БД указывать относительный путь до изображения, который выглядит как-то так `../../mainApp/img/logo.png`, картинки стали загружаться, но опять же уверен что это корявое решение

Answer (score 0):

Так должно сработать.
В шаблоне

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static mainApp/img/logo.png %}">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{movie.img}}">
```

замените на

```
<img src="{{movie.img.url}}">
```

Будет выведена относительная ссылка на изображение. Если не отображается, поиграйтесь с `urls.py` или раздавайте серез nginx

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас в файле с настройками (settings.py) стоит значение DEBUG = True, то нужно указывать относительный путь от папки со статикой.

В этом же файле укажите:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR/'static']
```

Соответственно, положите рядом с приложениями папку static (ну или другую, только в настройках укажите ее имя). Далее все просто, в шаблон передаем относительный путь от ДОМЕН/ , например:

```
<img src="/static/logo.png">
```

ИЛИ

Если у вас в файле с настройками (settings.py) стоит значение DEBUG = False, то запустите приложение командой:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.109:9000 --insecure
```

предварительно проделав указанное выше. Так уж получилось, что статику должен обслуживать не Django, а какой-нибудь nginx, поэтому статика работает только в режиме отладки, но если уж сильно хочется средствами Django, то insecure решит проблему.